# Convert number to binary and hex in C

Tags: c, base-conversion

I want to a write a program that converts a number to binary and hex.I tried to do this but It gives me the wrong result

```
int n, c, k;
int t = 0;
int binary[8];
for (c = 31; c >= 0; c--) {
    k = num >> c;
    if (k & 1) {
        printf("1");
        int binary[t] = 1;
    } else {
        printf("0");
        int binary[t] = 0;
    }
    ++t;
}
```

Comment: Just a sidenote, if you try to convert floating pt numbers in future into there corresponding binary or hexa, you may stumble across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100490/11498773)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-decimal-binary-conversion/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488377/converting-an-integer-to-binary-in-c

Comment: A few observations: (1) if you want to store values in your `binary` array, just use `binary[t] = ...`.  The extra `int` on those lines is meaningless and is causing problems. (2) Decide whether you want to print `1`/`0` out immediately, or store it in an array; you probably don't want to do both. (3) If you're making 32 trips through this loop and filling in the array, you had better make your `binary[]` array that big, too.  But other than those points, it looks like your code would work.  (For binary conversion, at least.  Hex will be another story.)

Comment: 1. Please tell us which output on which input you expect and what you get.

Comment: 2. Now that I have edited your code, can you see errors?